# Installing latest Gnome

Tags: gnome, gui

I like Gnome. I want to come back to Ubuntu
If I install gnome, will I get gnome 3.10?
If it will install Gnome 3.10 then tell me. So I can switch to Ubuntu 13.10 and intall Gnome 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gnome in 13.10. I just did an apt-get upgrade to ensure it was the latest version. The version check produced:

```
~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to install [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/), but if you really want the hard way, here it is:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html

### WARNING: THIS WILL BREAK UNITY!

#### and lightDM doesn't work

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

and for some apps

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-documents gnome-contacts epiphany-browser gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool bijiben gnome-clocks
```

and remove the weird scrollbar

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar
```

then reboot.

Comment: It didn't worked. I have to install Ubuntu again because it don't show anything when I did every command listed above.
There was some kind of low graphics error after reboot.

Comment: If you get low graphics error, just google it. Generally it can be solved by doing 'sudo apt-get install gdm'

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: If you really must re install, remember to et your files out using a live USB, then if you want GNOME, I suggest Ubuntu GNOME, where all the work is done for you.